# Few columns retrieved as "null" after running SQL query in C#

Tags: c#, sql-server, linq, linq-to-sql, linq-to-entities

I have implemented LINQ to Entities in Web API solution to implement "slow search" on given string.

Mapping SQL query with `dbContext.database.SQLQuery<Table>` syntax and finally receiving collection of rows.

The table has 3 columns:

```
AccountID (Guid)
Motor Name (NVARCHAR(50)
Motor Number (NVARCHAR(30)
```

`AccountID` column is retrieved with correct Guid values, whereas the other 2 columns are found as `null` when debugging and checked property values. Although, in database these columns do have values.

To verify, I ran the same SQL query in SSMS - and here, the columns value are correctly displayed.

SQL query is:

```
DECLARE @search NVARCHAR(10)
DECLARE @factor INT

SELECT AccountID, MotorName, MotorNumber
FROM MotorStore
WHERE DIFFERENCE(MotorName, @search) >= @factor
```

I appreciate if community shares some direction.

Can someone also share the LINQ equivalent of above query?

Comment: It would be awesome if you could provide a [mcve].

Answer (score 0):

You could do this easily by using Difference method in System.Data.Objects.SqlClient namespace like below.

```
            var res = from c in ctx.MotorStore
                      where SqlFunctions.Difference(c.MotorName,"searchstring")> factor
```

I suggest you to go through the article here.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.objects.sqlclient.sqlfunctions.difference?view=netframework-4.5.2